# How to show "npm outdated" current != wanted lines only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, console, npm

When I type `npm outdated` it displays something similar to

```
Package      Current   Wanted    Latest  Location
columnify      1.1.0    1.1.0     1.2.1  /usr/local/lib > npm > columnify
cmd-shim       1.1.2    1.1.2     2.0.0  /usr/local/lib > npm > cmd-shim
...
```

I do not care much about cases when "Current" is the same as "Wanted". Is there a way to filter this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm outdated | awk '$2!=$3'` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This does the trick. I guess I'll make an alias. Just wish npm had a flag for that.

Comment: When do you care about the output of this command? When you are already using a newer package than is "Wanted" on your system? When "Current" is behind "Wanted"? (I would assume that would be some sort of error case that it already checks for.)

Comment: When "Current" is behind "Wanted"

Comment: Does `npm` really allow that without giving warning? Is there not a "dependency checking" command for that purpose if there isn't a general warning?

Comment: npm highlights such row with red; however, on a big project the list gets huge and scrolling for red ones is annoying.

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a ticket with npm to get a flag added for "broken dependencies" or some-such.